# MongoDB upsert with $inc and $addToSet

Tags: php, mongodb

My sample code:

```
<?php
$m = new Mongo();

$db = $m->selectDB('metrics');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'counter');

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip = '192.168.1.1';
$user = 'testuser';
$today = date('Y-m-d');

//upsert 1st
$filter = array('url' => $url, 'date' => $today);
$data2 = array(
                '$inc' => array("pageview" => 1),
                '$addToSet' => array('visitors' => array('ip' => $ip))
);
$options = array("upsert" => true);
$collection->update( $filter, $data2, $options );


//update the pageview for unique ip after that
$filter1 = array( 'url' => $url, 'date' => $today, 'visitors' => array( '$elemMatch' => array( 'ip' => $ip ) ) );
$update1 = array( '$inc' => array( 'visitors.$.pageview' => 1 ) );
$collection->update( $filter1, $update1 );

?>
```

Data in mongodb:

This is correct when view the page for 1st time.

```
> db.counter.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fdaaf1176c5c9fca444ffd3"), "date" : "2012-06-14", "pageview" : 1, "url" : "/mongo/test.php", "visitors" : [ { "ip" : "192.168.1.1", "pageview" : 1 } ] }
```

After refresh the page, adding weird data:

```
> db.counter.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fdaaf1176c5c9fca444ffd3"), "date" : "2012-06-14", "pageview" : 2, "url" : "/mongo/test.php", "visitors" : [ { "ip" : "192.168.1.1", "pageview" : 2 }, { "ip" : "192.168.1.1" } ] }
```

How would I correct query and prevent the extra IP from being inserted? Thanks.

Comment: Is your intention to have one document per URL per IP or one document per URL (with an array of IPs)?

Comment: I prefer 1 document per ip because can track hitting per ip

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right your pasted code is executed everytime in this way?
The problem that you get another ip entry is `'$addToSet' => array('visitors' => array('ip' => $ip))'$addToSet' => array('visitors' => array('ip' => $ip))` as your array doesn't contain a field with only an ip it will insert another one(your field has additionally an pageview attribute). You would need to have an exact match.
Not sure if theres some guideline for this problem, but I think you should go with something like this, as document structure:

{_id:ObjectId(.....),..., visitors: { 192.168.1.1: {pageview:1}}. So you can simply run this update command (in mongoshell syntax), which further combines both updates into one :):

`db.c.update({"url":"/test.php","date":"today"},{$inc : {"192.168.1.1" : {pageview:1}, pageview: 1}},true)` to update your document. Anyway you need to replace those dots with some other character as it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: I can make it done using nested array, but I want to achieve this by using embed document. Thanks.

Comment: Your current solution is based upon an array filled with documents. SO you may be a bit on the wrong track about your approach( If I got you correctly). Indeed you can do it with your initial document structure, but this may be not as handy as it could be.
I think you need for your solution multiple queries which may fail or cause data duplication as described due to concurrent mongodb updates to the same document (although this is untested and just a guess). Why do you want to use an array with documents filled and not my approach?

Comment: Maybe you got my example wrong, sorry if I truncated it wrong. Those dots mean to represent your other data as well:
`{_id:ObjectId(.....),date:"today", url:"test/address.php", visitors: { 192.168.1.1: {pageview:1}, 10.2.42.1: {pageview:3}`