# Upserting with codeigniter's mongo-db library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

I am using a mongodb-codeigniter library by [Alex Bilbie](https://github.com/alexbilbie/MongoQB).

I have a collection called "user_visits". I insert into collection like below.

```
$query = $this->mongo_db->insert('user_restaurant_visits',[
    '_id' => 1,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'pages_visited' => [    
                'page_id' => $restaurant_id 
                'visited' => [
                                'deal' => $purchase_deal,
                                'ordered' => $purchased_item
                             ]
                        ]
        ]);
```

Now all I would want to know is,

- I would like to add the documents by "upsert=true" boolean flag as specified in [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) which will insert if the field is not present and update if the field is present. And I could not find a way to do so in the library I use! Am I misguided?
- Is this a good way? is there anything wrong in the way I have organized the fields (I mean Schema as we say in RDBMS). I specifically ask this because, some feel nested arrays are better than embedded documents. like philnate says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044405/mongodb-upsert-with-inc-and-addtoset) in his answer and comments
- If I'd want to upsert, increment a field, and addToSet, in the same query, is this possible with the library I currently use?

Let me know if I miss something, I can clarify in comments. I am totally new to NoSQL DBs.
I am sorry if that looked amaeturish.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of one of your question :

How to Use `"Upsert"` in `CodeIgniter` while updating :

```
// Where Condition, if any
$this->mongo_db->where(array('condition_key' => 'condition_value'));

// Update Data Array
$this->mongo_db->set($mongoArray); 

// Set Options
$option = array('upsert' => true);

// Call Update Function
$this->mongo_db->update('Collection_Name', $option);
```

I hope this will help you :)